# Unable to find ahadmin.h file 

Tags: c++, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows 64 bit machine (windows server 2008) & have IIS 7.5. When I try to build one of project which is in C++, it shows ahadmin.h file missing.

I am very new to IIS server project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924). It doesn't seems like this file comes with Visual Studio, but it's part of the SDK.